# Django Rest Framework create nested objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have seen similar questions but they are from 2012. Django Rest Framework has changed since then.

So, I have a Profile model that references the django User model. I have a ProfileSerializer that looks like this:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'image', 'decription', 'city', 'phone_number']
```

The UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_obj = User.objects.create(first_name=validated_data['first_name'], last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                       email=validated_data['email'])
        user_obj.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user_obj.save()
        return user_obj

    class Meta:
        model = User
        write_only_fields = ['password']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

The Browsable Api shows the user field as a dropdown with the registered users, I need it to show the UserSerializer fields so that the view could create both, the Profile object and the User object at once, the view:

```
class RegisterUser(generics.CreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

Is it possible?

**Edit, add the model:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    image = models.UrlField()
    ....
```

So, is it possible to create both, the nested User object and the Profile object with one CreateAPIView? Or should I do it in two steps. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there a `OneToOne` field from the `Profile` model to the `User` model? Can you post your `Profile` model please?

Comment: @jape added the models, yes, I use a `OneToOneField`.